# Finding paths in a path connected space

Tags: gn.general-topology, gt.geometric-topology

I'm looking for such literature as exists relevant to the following problem.

*Problem*  Given a compact, path-connected region $E$ on the plane and a positive constant $r$.   Find (if possible) a path $P$ in $E$ with the following property: Given a point $p \in E$, there exists a point $q $ lying on $P$ such that $||q-p|| \leq r$ , where $||$ is Euclidean distance.

I am also interested in the following variants of the Problem:

1. What conditions have $E$ has to satisfy for a $P$ to exist?

   Can we find the set of all such paths?

   If we restrict $P$ to be $n$-times differentiable, under what conditions does it exist?

I'm aware that these variants may lead to a combinatorial explosion of answers for each special case. Hence, would be grateful for links to foundational literature.

Comment: $P$ always exists---take a countable dense subset of $E$, enumerate it, and connect the points in order...

Comment: @Daniel: How do we connect points when $P$ has to be $n$-times differentiable?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "region"?

Comment: The Hahn–Mazurkiewicz theorem says that, under mild topological assumptions on $E$, there exists a *surjective* path (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve). Of course these space-fillers may be extremely non-differentiable.

Comment: I'm assuming that region implies open (otherwise it's easy to create problems). In that case, Daniel Litt's solution sounds pretty solid to me. Making the path n times differentiable should not be a problem.